# Computing parallel polygons based on given perpendicular distance in GeoPandas

Tags: python, geopandas, shapely, polygon-creation, geodataframe

Say I have a GeoPandas `GeoDataFrame` of polygons (i.e. the `"geometry"` column contains polygons of GPS coordinates only).

```
import geopandas as gpd
from shapely.geometry import Polygon

lat_point_list = [50.854457, 52.518172, 50.072651, 48.853033, 50.854457]
lon_point_list = [4.377184, 13.407759, 14.435935, 2.349553, 4.377184]

polygon_geom = Polygon(zip(lon_point_list, lat_point_list))
polygon = gpd.GeoDataFrame(index=[0], crs='epsg:4326', geometry=[polygon_geom]) 


#Visualizing this polygon
import folium
m = folium.Map([50.854457, 4.377184], zoom_start=5, tiles='cartodbpositron')
folium.GeoJson(polygon).add_to(m)
folium.LatLngPopup().add_to(m)
m
```

[image]

I want to compute a new `GeoDataFrame` with a new `"geometry"` column of polygons where the new polygons are parallel to the old ones with a given perpendicular distance `d`.

If `d` is positive, the new polygons are larger than the old ones and encompass them. If `d` is negative, the new polygons are smaller than the old ones and are contained within them.

```
d = 100.  #let's assume the unit of kilometres

#construct new bigger polygons that have all sides parallel to and 100 kilometres outside of the above smaller polygon


d = -50
#construct new smaller polygons that have all sides parallel to and 50 kilometres inside of the above bigger polygon
```

How would I do this efficiently, with a solution generalized for any kind of polygon?

Answer (score 5):

You can use [`buffer`](https://geopandas.org/en/stable/docs/reference/api/geopandas.GeoSeries.buffer.html#geopandas-geoseries-buffer) method with the `join_style=2` option (2 refers `mitre`) for visualization purposes.

```py
import geopandas as gpd
from math import pi
from shapely.geometry import Polygon

lat_point_list = [50.854457, 52.518172, 50.072651, 48.853033, 50.854457]
lon_point_list = [4.377184, 13.407759, 14.435935, 2.349553, 4.377184]

polygon_geom = Polygon(zip(lon_point_list, lat_point_list))
polygon_df = gpd.GeoDataFrame(index=[0], crs='epsg:4326', geometry=[polygon_geom]) 

# positive distance
d = 100 # km
d = d * 180 / (pi * 6371) # approx. degree equivalent on Earth sphere
polygon1_df = polygon_df.buffer(d, join_style=2)

# negative distance
d = -30 # km
d = d * 180 / (pi * 6371) # approx. degree equivalent on Earth sphere
polygon2_df = polygon_df.buffer(d, join_style=2)

#Visualizing this polygon
import folium
m = folium.Map([50.854457, 4.377184], zoom_start=5, tiles='cartodbpositron')

folium.GeoJson(polygon_df).add_to(m)

style_function = lambda x: {"fillOpacity": 0, "color": "#ff0000"}
folium.GeoJson(polygon1_df, style_function).add_to(m)
folium.GeoJson(polygon2_df, style_function).add_to(m)

folium.LatLngPopup().add_to(m)
m
```

The result looks a bit incorrect because of the transformation from EPSG:4326 (polygon's CRS) to EPSG 3857 (basemap's CRS).

[image]